# ember remove association from hasMany

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data

I have a hasMany relation ship in ember and i would like to remove the association between the two records. This is what i tried:

```
@model.get('companies').removeObject(company)
@model.save()
```

Although it does remove the association on the frontend. The query doesn't sent something like this:

```
company_ids: [1]
```

Does anybody know how i can get the query to also include an array of ids?

Comment: what about `model.get('companies').then(function(companies){companies.removeObject(company)})`

Comment: Hi altrim, sadly its not the problem in the array. I can remove the object with the code above. But the query doesn't sent: company_ids: [].

Comment: There is currently an issue with saving `hasMany` relationships in ember data. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25212012/104376 for a solution.

Comment: Hey tikotzky, thanxs! I didn't see that yet. :) Thanxs mate!