# Saving a model breaks one to many relationships

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When I save a Parent object (which has many Child objects), the relationship is seemingly broken. The [Ember docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/persisting-records/) are silent on this issue.

What do I need to do so that the Parent object still shows the Child objects?

When this action is run, I expect the Parent name will be changed from "Taylor" to "Matt", and the Child, "Ben", will be unchanged and remain on the page. Currently, the action removes the Child from the Parent.

```
saveParent: function() {
  this.store.find('parent', 1).then(function (parent) {
    parent.set('name', 'Matt');
    parent.save();
    });
}
```

jsbin example: http://jsbin.com/zodorule/8/

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with the JSONSerializer and hasMany relationships.  You can check this 'fixed' jsbin: http://jsbin.com/zodorule/13

Refer to this issue: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-data-fixture-adapter-saving-record-loses-has-many-relationships/2821

I added this to your code and it works:

```
DS.JSONSerializer.reopen({
    serializeHasMany : function(record, json, relationship) {
        var key = relationship.key;

        var relationshipType = DS.RelationshipChange.determineRelationshipType(
                record.constructor, relationship);

        if (relationshipType === 'manyToNone'
                || relationshipType === 'manyToMany'
                || relationshipType === 'manyToOne') {
            json[key] = Ember.get(record, key).mapBy('id');
            // TODO support for polymorphic manyToNone and manyToMany
            // relationships
        }
    }
});
```